# MVC Custom Error Ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A question about the complicated topic that is MVC ASP.NET custom errors.  I have read and followed several guides on SO and http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

I understand most apsects and in general it works but with this exception:

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/500.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404.aspx" />  
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

URL that ends in less than sign
http://localhost/site/<
correctly results in the default Error/500.aspx error page being displayed.

But if there is any other character after the less than sign in the URL then I get the .Net Runtime Error page.

This article mentions a similar issue to do with dots in the URL and suggests using URL Rewrite to solve the problem.  http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/08/error-handling-in-mvc-and-nice-error-pages/

However, I have not been able to adapt this to deal with < and > characters.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: What is the .NET Runtime error you're getting?

Comment: If I try to browse to http://localhost/<a I get the following:

The browser displays an error page:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: Well, the explanation is rather obvious then. Your error page itself has an error. Throw a bunch of try/catch around your error page logic until you figure out exactly what it is that's breaking. Keep in mind your error page needs to be extremely robust to avoid situations like this.

Comment: Event viewer gives more details:

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/< 
    Request path: /< 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Comment: The URL http://localhost/< displays the custom error fine, but http://localhost/<a does not.

Comment: The custom error is very basic:

<% Response.StatusCode = 500 %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>ERROR: 500 - Error/500.aspx</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The thing throwing the exception is likely within ASP.NET in this scenario, and avoiding it may mean you need to turn off the request validation or do some URL rewriting etc. I doubt either of those are very attractive options. Why do you care? Do you really expect users to be submitting URL's like this to your app with the expectation they'll get a nice error page?

Comment: I am just inquisitive.  I am trying to ascertain if I am doing something wrong or if there is a bug in the IIS / ASP.NET pipeline.  I fail to understand why both URLs throw the same dangerous Request.Path exception (and report it in event viewer) but only one of those URLs results in the custom error page being displayed when it is my understanding that IIS should handle them both the same way according to my configuration.

Comment: A quick update - reviewing the .NET source, this makes more sense.  The url that ends <a is deemed unsafe by method call System.Web.CrossSiteScriptingValidation.IsDangerousString.  From the comment this is be design: "switch (s[n]) {
                case '<':
                    // If the < is followed by a letter or '!', it's unsafe (looks like a tag or HTML comment)"  All that is left to understand is why a dangerous URL bypasses custom error pages.

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour, with the exact same code as you. A Chinese hacker entered `...` somewhere in the URL. Tried removing the `~` from the redirect path, but as expected, same behaviour. Did you figure this out?